# Run multiple test opening mutilple instances of windows application(VB .NET) using one UFT instance

Tags: automated-tests, hp-uft

Application Under test is developed using .net vb .

Clarification 1 :

is it possible to run multiple tests parellel using one instance of UFT in a one machine ?

Clarification 2  :

Can we open multiple instances of the windows application and run different tests on each instance of the the opened windows application in parellel .

Answer (score 0):

This will not workout with windows application. Even the application is minimized the objects will not be able to identify with UFT until the window is activated. Both the criteria will not work as the objects are just like that identified by their properties not by creation time as we use it for browser. Only option is running multiple test cases in multiple machines

Answer (score 0):

UFT doesn't support running tests in parallel. Note that UFT simulates users, each tests assumes it controls where the focus is (sometimes by taking control of the mouse and keyboard for typing). If multiple tests are trying to do this you may get unexpected results just like you would if you had two mice connected to your computer and two people tried to do different things at the same time.

Consider the following two tests:

**Test A**

- Click *username* edit field
- Type "hello"

**Test B**

- Click *password* edit field
- Type "world"

When run in parallel you may get:

- Click *password* edit field
- Click *username* edit field
- Type "hello"
- Type "world"